# StackOverFlow Exception, alternatives for my function?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I've created a program that at some point has to log in to some website. If something goes wrong, I want it to wait for some time, say 2 seconds, and then try again. so the function looks something like this:

```
public void log_in ()
{
    try
    {
        //login code
    }
    catch
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        log_in();
    }
}
```

But this code started to give me StackOverFlowExeptions every now and then. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a stack overflow exception because every time you call `log_in()` you're adding the function to the stack. This this:

```
public void log_in ()
{
    while (true) {
        try
        {
            //login code
            return;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what's because if code can't login at all it keeps creating new function call each time on the stack. Next code would work:

```
public void log_in ()
{
    while(true) {
       try {
          //login code
          return;
       }
       catch {
           Thread.Sleep(2000);
       }
    }
}
```

But overall you shouldn't try to login endlessly, after several time report error to user/admin.